# tileserver-gl running within docker container - run error

Tags: node.js, docker, ubuntu, tileserver-gl

I am building a Docker image using the below Dockerfile and the command "`docker build -t tiler_test -f Dockerfile .`". The building works fine.  However when I try to run the Dockerfile with "`docker run -p 8080:8080 tiler_test:latest`" I get the following error message which I've tried many things to resolve w/o success.

```
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1473
  return process.dlopen(module, path.toNamespacedPath(filename));
                 ^

Error: libGLX.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
    at Module._extensions..node (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1473:18)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1207:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1023:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1235:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/helpers:176:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/tileserver-gl/node_modules/@maplibre/maplibre-gl-            native/platform/node/index.js:5:12)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1376:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1435:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1207:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1023:12) {
  code: 'ERR_DLOPEN_FAILED'
}

Node.js v20.11.1
```

Dockerfile

```
# Use an Ubuntu base image
FROM ubuntu:latest

# Install dependencies
RUN apt-get update && \
apt-get install -y wget curl git unzip build-essential python3

# Install Node.js
RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_20.x | bash - && \
apt-get install -y nodejs

# Clone TileServer-GL repository
RUN git clone https://github.com/klokantech/tileserver-gl.git /tileserver-gl

# Change working directory
WORKDIR /tileserver-gl

# Install TileServer-GL dependencies
RUN npm install
RUN npm install -g npm@10.5.0
RUN npm install -g tileserver-gl

WORKDIR /

COPY ./config.json /config.json
COPY ./test.mbtiles /test.mbtiles
COPY templates /templates
COPY styles /styles
COPY fonts /fonts

# Expose the default TileServer-GL port
EXPOSE 8080
ENV PORT 8080
ENTRYPOINT ["tileserver-gl"]
CMD "tileserver-gl --file test.mbtiles"
```

I tried running the docker image with:

```
docker build -t tiler_test -f Dockerfile .
```

and get the error message cited in description.   I was expecting for the CMD to run and be able to access the resulting tileserver-gl map tile server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were missing a few libraries. See the `Dockerfile` below where they are installed in the last line of the first `apt-get install` command.

```
FROM ubuntu:latest

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y \
        wget \
        curl \
        git \
        unzip \
        build-essential \
        python3 \
        libglx-dev libopengl0 libuv1-dev

RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_20.x | bash - && \
    apt-get install -y \
        nodejs

RUN git clone https://github.com/klokantech/tileserver-gl.git /tileserver-gl

WORKDIR /tileserver-gl

RUN npm install
RUN npm install -g npm@10.5.0 tileserver-gl

WORKDIR /

RUN wget https://github.com/maptiler/tileserver-gl/releases/download/v1.3.0/zurich_switzerland.mbtiles

EXPOSE 8080
ENV PORT 8080

CMD tileserver-gl --file zurich_switzerland.mbtiles
```

For the purpose of illustration I'm download a file with tiles during the build process.

[image]